# Using “let alone” + (only) adverb

Tags: grammaticality

Could “let alone” be used as in the following sentence?

- *This benefit should not be rejected, let alone  hastily.*

Here the “let alone” clause does not mirror “be rejected”; instead, it only has an adverb.
Is it grammatical or not?

Does the second clause forcefully need to say: *"**be rejected** hastily"*?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: It's certainly understandable in speech. To be picky, just add "Let alone **do it** hastily."

Comment: Repeat _rejected_, but not _be_: _This benefit should not be rejected, let alone rejected hastily._ You can almost always delete meaningless parts like auxiliaries and prepositions, but repeating meaningful parts makes them more emphatic, and that's what's needed with the [_let alone_ construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/319151/15299).

Answer (score 2):

Something in the first clause needs to mirror "hastily" for "let alone" to mean anything. You could say something like this:

> This benefit should not be rejected **at all**, let alone hastily.

That is, not only should the benefit not be rejected *hastily*, it should not be rejected *at all*.